# Conflict with android support version on cordova build android

Tags: android, cordova, android-support-library

this is a common error, but in this case don't know how to solve this. What I do:

> cordova build android

And it return this:

```
$ cordova build android
Running command: "/app/platforms/android/cordova/build" 
ANDROID_HOME=/Android SDK/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
Running: /app/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /app/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:compileLint
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:preBuild
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:preDebugBuild
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:checkDebugManifest
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:preDebugTestBuild
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:compileDebugAidl
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:compileDebugRenderscript
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:mergeDebugAssets
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:generateDebugResources
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:mergeDebugResources
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:processDebugManifest
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:processDebugResources
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:generateDebugSources
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:compileDebugJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:packageDebugJar
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:compileDebugNdk
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:packageDebugLocalJar
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:packageDebugResources
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:bundleDebug
:prepareAndroidComPhonegapPluginsFacebookconnectFacebookLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:preReleaseBuild
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:checkReleaseManifest
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedReleaseLibrary
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:compileReleaseAidl
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:compileReleaseRenderscript
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:mergeReleaseAssets
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:generateReleaseResources
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:mergeReleaseResources
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:processReleaseManifest
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:processReleaseResources
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:generateReleaseSources
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:compileReleaseJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:packageReleaseJar
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:compileReleaseNdk
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:packageReleaseLocalJar
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:packageReleaseResources
:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect:FacebookLib:bundleRelease
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds810Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources
:processDebugManifest
:processDebugResources
:generateDebugSources
:compileDebugJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:preDexDebug
:dexDebug

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:dexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Android SDK/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/app/platforms/android/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 30.368 secs

/app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /app/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/app/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /app/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /app/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
```

So I understand that is a conflict of versions between android-support-v4 and android-support-v13 but don't know how to solve this.

> $ cordova -v
> 5.4.0
>
> $ cordova platform
> Installed platforms: android 4.1.1, ios 3.8.0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I will bet that it's the Facebook plugin that's causing the collision. Try adding this to your `platforms/android/build.gradle` file:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: Where should i? inside buildscript()

Comment: add it before android {
    sourceSets { and same error