# :CordovaLib:processDebugResources FAILED

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, centos7

Using ionic to build android app :

```
[root@localhost ionic-app-base-master]# ionic build android
```

Console log show those messages :

```
Running command: /root/ionic-tutorial/conference/ionic-app-base-master/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /root/ionic-tutorial/conference/ionic-app-base-master
    add to body class: platform-android
    ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/lib/android-sdk
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45
    :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :checkDebugManifest
    :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:compileLint
    :CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
    :CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
    :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:processDebugResources FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
    > A problem occurred starting process 'command '/usr/local/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt''

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 2.503 secs
    Error: Error code 1 for command: /root/ionic-tutorial/conference/ionic-app-base-master/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/root/ionic-tutorial/conference/ionic-app-base-master/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

I check many tickets & i perform many changes , like :

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30842231/747579
2. [Conflict with android support version on cordova build android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899826/conflict-with-android-support-version-on-cordova-build-android)
3. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-android-build-problem/29131/5

Known that the current `config.xml` is :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
    <author email="me@abdennoor.com" href="http://abdennoor.com">
      Abdennour TOUMI
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />

    <!-- Ionic supports Android Jellybean and up --> 
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />

    <!-- Don't store local data in an iCloud backup. Turn this to "cloud" to enable storage 
         to be sent to iCloud. Note: enabling this could result in Apple rejecting your app.
    -->
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />

    <feature name="StatusBar">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

## My Environment :

```
   Android SDK   :  23.1.0
   Ionic         : 1.7.4
   Cordova       : 6.1.0
   gradle        : 2.2.1
   JVM           : 1.8.0_45 (Oracle Corporation 25.45-b02)

   Groovy        : 2.3.6
   Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
   OS:           Linux 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 amd64
```

Comment: Have you checked whether `/usr/local/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt` exist or not? If not, maybe your `Android SDK Build-tools` version is not compatible with your project.

Comment: @刘文壮 : Thanks a lot for this hint .. i will try

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are trying to run the Android SDK (installed on a 32bit file) on a 64bit system.
I solve the problem running the commands bellow on Ubuntu. Depending on your system try one of theses options:

#### If you are using a Ubuntu 32bit version

> *sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev*

#### If your Ubuntu is a 64bit and its version is <= 13.04, run:

> *sudo apt-get install ia32-libs*

#### In case of Ubuntu 64bit and version >=13.10, run:

> *sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev:i386*

Comment: I had the Ubuntu 16.04 on 64bit case and your solution worked for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: and if I am on Mac OS X ?

Comment: Question is tagged [tag:centos7] not [tag:ubuntu].. However, thank you for taking time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

Review your files names, i had the same problem and solved by removing special characters from files names.